# ASP.NET filter column SQL data source at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql

I am trying to build a sample webpage using ASP.NET and this is my first try.

i dont know how to explain this but anyways here is it

In design time

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AAAAConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ABC], [firstname], [lastname], [companyname], [email], [phone], [fax] FROM [XYZ]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In runtime I want to filter the columns in select command (say first name and lastname alone)

Comment: SELECT firstname, lastname from db

Comment: @NSmeef, that doesn't exactly filter the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SqlDataSource.FilterExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property

> Gets or sets a filtering expression that is applied when the Select
>   method is called.

For example;

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AAAAConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [ABC], [firstname], [lastname], [companyname], [email], [phone], [fax] FROM [XYZ]"
     FilterExpression="firstname ='Adhithya' and lastname = 'lyer'">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: I want to filter the columns in the tables and not rows
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlDataSource and create 2 parameters with LIKE condition and make the default value %
Here is an example for one TextBox:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CosmicConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [ItemGroupId], [GroupNameArabic], [GroupNameEnglish] FROM [CategoriesView] WHERE ([GroupNameEnglish] LIKE '%' + @GroupNameEnglish + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFilter" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%" Name="GroupNameEnglish" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by code

```
var sql = "SELECT [ABC], [firstname], [lastname], [companyname], [email], [phone], [fax] FROM [XYZ]";
if (condition)
{
    sql = "SELECT [firstname], [lastname] FROM [XYZ]";
}
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sql;
gvS.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged() to re fetch and bind the data, and then use the DropDownList.SelectedValue to determine which columns you want to be selected/visible?

Answer (score 0):

Have a `DropDownList` containing all the Columns of the Table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'Table_Name'
```

Create a `ListBox` and a Button for Adding the `DropDownList` values to the `ListBox`.

```
listBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(dropDownList.SelectedItem.Text));
// Usually I'd remove the column from the DropDownList too and then add it back if removing a column from the ListBox
dropDownList.Items.Remove(dropDownList.SelectedItem);
```

Have a Method that iterates through the `ListBox` to set the `SelectCommand` for a `SqlDataSource`:

```
private void UpdateSelectCommand() {
    string selectCommand = "SELECT Table_Name.ID";
    
    // For each Column in the ListBox gets added to the select command.
    foreach (ListItem li in colsList.Items)
    {
       selectCommand = selectCommand + " , Table_Name." + li.Text;
    }
    
    sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = selectCommand + " FROM Table_Name " +
    "ORDER BY Table_Name.ID";
}
```